# leave a column alone while replacing in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, replace

so suppose there's a table:

```
id column1 column2

 1   333     4444
```

Where id is a primary key

And then I do

```
REPLACE INTO table (id, column2) VALUES (1, 55)
```

This will cause column1 to become null...is there a way to specify the query such that it will leave whatever existing value of column1 is when REPLACE matches an existing entry?

Comment: @ChrisW: "*Where id is a primary key*"

Comment: @eggyal - ah, oops - would help if I didn't miss vital parts of the question out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO table (id, column2) VALUES (1, 55)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column2 = VALUES(column2)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to MySQL [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html), no you can't.
But you can INSERT ... on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.